# Kotlin/Java: Override Abstract Value in Subclass Constructor

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

Given an abstract class:

```kotlin
abstract class BobaTea {
    abstract val sweetness: Int
}
```

I have a subclass in which I want to override `sweetness`, however I want to do that in the constructor because the value of sweetness cannot be defined at compile-time, I will only know it at run-time. However, my constructor will ensure that all instances of the subclass do indeed implement the abstract value `sweetness`.

```kotlin
class MatchaBobaLatte : BobaTea() {
    constructor(sweetness: Int) : this() {
        this.sweetness = sweetness  // This fails with "val cannot be reassigned"
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I am not *reassigning* `sweetness`, I am simply overriding it because it is abstract in the superclass.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but in Java abstract methods need to be declared concretely before they can actually be used.  Since your value is abstract, perhaps it needs some concrete definition.

Comment: Because it's abstract in the superclass, you haven't _defined_ it enough so that Kotlin can decide if there _is_ a `this.sweetness` or not.  (It could also be a getter, for example.)  You must specify this in the subtype with `override`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overriding an abstract property requires that you override it at the top level and mention `override val` somewhere.

It can happen either in the primary constructor, e.g.

```
class MatchaBobaLatte(override val sweetness: Int) : BobaTea() {
    // ...
}
```

or by explicitly declaring the override val like

```
class MatchaBobaLatte : BobaTea {
    override val sweetness: Int

    constructor(sweetness: Int) : super() { // Not this()!
        this.sweetness = sweetness
    }
}
```

or like

```
class MatchaBobaLatte(sweetness: Int) : BobaTea() {
    // primary constructor parameters are available for instance
    // initializer code
    override val sweetness = sweetness * 2
}
```

The error you see is result of a combination of multiple things. You try to delegate to a primary `this()` constructor which doesn't exist but it would be the one that needs to set all `val` values. The error also appears if you would do

```kotlin
class Reassign {
    val sweetness: Int; // when no value here, then

    // primary ctor must init all vals or you get
    // "Property must be initialized or be abstract"
    constructor() {
        sweetness = 42;
    }

    // can't touch vals in here any more because it runs
    // after "this()"
    constructor(foo: Int) : this() {
        sweetness = foo; // Val cannot be reassigned
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I see, I did forget the meaning of `this()` vs `super()`. And defining the overridden val up top but then initializing it in the constructor is something I tried but must have failed due to the `this()` delegation. Thank you!